# Pairwise tangent circles radical axes

Tags: geometry

> Three pairwise tangent circles are drawn with the three common tangents to each of the pairs of circles. Prove that the common tangents must intersect at a point.

Since the tangents to the circles are the radical axes,we could say that the three lines concur at the radical axis. But what do it mean to concur at the radical axis?

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that all three tangents are parallel. This case must be excluded from the statement of the problem.

Let $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ be the circles, and let $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, $a_{23}$, be the tangents at the points of tangency $A_{12}$, $A_{13}$, $A_{23}$, of the three circles. Assume, for example, that $a_{12}$ and $a_{13}$ meet at $P$.

Point $P$ has the same power $PA_{12}^2$ with respect to circles $C_1$ and $C_2$. Similarly, $P$ has the same power $PA_{13}^2$ with respect to circles $C_1$ and $C_3$. Since $P$ has the same power with respect to circles $C_2$ and $C_3$, it must belong to the radical axis of $C_2$ and $C_3$. But this is $a_{23}$. Therefore, $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$ and $a_{23}$ meet at $P$.

Comment: I don't see how all three tangents can be parallel if they all must be pairwise tangent.

Comment: Take $A$, $B$, $C$ so that $B$ is the midpoint of $AC$. Then the circles with diameters $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$ are pairwise tangent, and their tangents at $A$, $B$, $C$ are parallel.